# How to show React router links in Storybook MDX?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, storybook

I'm working on Storybook project and I would like to display links from react-router. I saw that it was possible to use `storybook-react-router`, but when I import and use it in my MDX story it does not display anything (but the code is visible). How could I fix it?

This is my MDX code:

```
<Canvas>
<StoryRouter>
    <List>
        <Link to="#">Link</Link>
        <Link to="#">Link</Link>
    </List>
</StoryRouter>
</Canvas>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm struggling with something similar as well. Our Stories are written in MDX and I haven't found any relevant example for that. I have a component which renders `Link` component from `react-router-dom` and I need to present it in Storybook.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I came up with the following. Does anyone have a better idea? I couldn't make `storybook-react-router` to work.

**story.mdx**

```
import { Meta, ArgsTable, Canvas, Story } from '@storybook/addon-docs';
import { Component } from 'Component';
import { useStoryReactRouterDecorator } from 'useStoryReactRouterDecorator'

<Meta
  title="Component"
  component={Component}
/>

<Canvas>
    <Story name="With React Router"
        args={paginationMocks.reactRouter}
        decorators={[useStoryReactRouterDecorator(['/sample-default-path'])]}
    >
        <Component prop="example" />
    </Story>
</Canvas>
```

**useStoryReactRouterDecorator.tsx**

```
import { StoryProps } from '@storybook/addon-docs'
import React, { FunctionComponent } from 'react'
import { MemoryRouter, Route, Routes, To, useLocation, useParams } from 'react-router-dom'

export const useStoryReactRouterDecorator = (initialEntries: To[]) => {
  return (Story: FunctionComponent<StoryProps>) => {
    return (
      <MemoryRouter initialEntries={initialEntries}>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="*" element={<LocationLogger />} />
        </Routes>
        <Story />
      </MemoryRouter>
    )
  }
}

const LocationLogger = (): JSX.Element => {
  const location = useLocation()
  const params = useParams()

  console.log('Navigated to', location, 'with params', params) // Or Storybook's action()
  return <></>
}
```